# multi select ctrl+button click at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, select, user-controls

On my winform I have usercontrols that are created dynamically at every button click. I want at runtime to be able to select them just by clicking once on them and then having  ctrl button pressed. I managed to do it ,but just for one . How can I make to work for all of them? My code:

```
  private void TControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //TControl is the name of usercontrol
    {
        TControl tc = new TControl();
        Control ctrl = sender as Control;
        if (ctrl != null)
       tc = ctrl;//it doesn't work like this.
```

Comment: What does it mean to "select" your user control?

Comment: Aren't controls selected when you click on them?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky `Control`s get "focus", right? But only one at a time.

Comment: I mean: I want to be able to select multiple controls in order to detele them,or copy them,etc.

Comment: @Mady other than your control you will have to create a custom list control which will work as a container for your control, Just like a list box which serves as a list container for strings, than your logic of handling ctrl and copy, paste etc will be written in that list container control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have list of selected controls. Just determine if Ctrl was pressed when you clicked on control and add it to selected list (you can also remove it if control was added before):

```
List<TControl> selectedControls = new List<TControl>();

private void TControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == 0)
        return;

    TControl tc = (TControl)sender;
    if (selectedControls.Contains(tc))
        return; // you can remove control here

    selectedControls.Add(tc);
}
```